# Transpose FeatureCollection export Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm exporting the pixel values from a set of points (n = 10,000) across the Landsat collection. At the moment the code exports each point as a new row; however, I would like each point to be a new column. Is is possible to transpose the FeatureCollection prior to the export

Link to the [export code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/db84f8f007f6e47f0fa331849392d2f3)

The main code snippet is

```
var mapfunc = function(feat) {
  var geom = feat.geometry();
  var addProp = function(img, f) {
    var newf = ee.Feature(f);
    var date = img.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd');
    var bands = img.bandNames();
    var value = img.select(bands)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), geom, 30);

    var fun = function(name, ini) {
      var ini = ee.Feature(ini)
      var val = value.get(name);
      var newname = ee.String(date).cat('-').cat(name);
      return ee.Feature(ee.Algorithms.If(val,
                        ini.set(newname, ee.String(val)),
                        ini.set(newname, ee.String('No data'))));
    };

    return ee.Feature(bands.iterate(fun, newf)); 

  };
  var newfeat = ee.Feature(overall_collection.iterate(addProp, feat));
  return newfeat;
};

var site_data = stable_points.map(mapfunc);
```

Comment: I assume this is a step in a larger processing job, or else you can simply do the transpose locally.

Comment: I am mainly concerned that when mapping the function over lots of points that I'm getting close to the maximum number of columns in the spreadsheet. If the output were transposed the number of columns would be approximately the same as the number points

Comment: You should export as a csv which has no column/row limitations.